# PHP Any ideas for check ip address with same host in wifi

Tags: php, ip, local

i tried to search , how to find local ip, is worked when i use

```
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

$computerName = gethostbyaddr($IP);

it display my host ip address, im using wifi in home, when my PC and other PC , and mobile is display same each other.

and. it possible how to check or detect the different pc with other pc in the same connection (wireless or lan)?

Comment: If environment is "friendly" (so you want that to be done and want to determine it somehow) - then you may realize that devices are different with, for example, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. But if env. is not "friendly" (someone tries to "hide" behind NAT) - then no way

Answer (score 1):

When multiple devices access the Internet through a router that implements NAT (as is typical for most home Internet usage), there is no way for servers on the Internet to get any IP address other then the routers Internet facing address.